# I am using tableview to load images from url but image repeating issue in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing image repeating issue, when try to scroll to downside or upside if image not loading completed then image repeat the same as complete the image downloaded. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"galCustom";

    GTInstaTableViewCell *cell = (GTInstaTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GTInstaTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    for (UIView *view in cell.imageView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    cell._imageLoadingView.hidden = NO;
    [cell._imageLoadingView startAnimating];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GTInstaTableViewCell *cell1 = (GTInstaTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Gallery Photo

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        NSString *strImgname = [[arrTabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo_name"];
        imgPname = [IMAGE_URL stringByAppendingString:strImgname];

        NSString *aPath = [self.thumbDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImgname];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath]) 
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgPname];
            NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            float containerWidth = 648.0;

            //Image Resize
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

            float width = image.size.width;
            float height= image.size.height;
            float thumbWidth = width/containerWidth;
            float imageHeight = height/thumbWidth;

            CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(containerWidth, imageHeight);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
            [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage);

            [imageData writeToFile:aPath atomically:YES];
         }

         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:aPath];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
         {
             if (image) 
             {
                 cell.imageView.image = image;
                 cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                 cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                 [cell1._imageLoadingView stopAnimating];
                 cell1._imageLoadingView.hidden = YES;
             }
             else
             {
                 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noImage.jpg"];
             }
         });
    });   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code properly. UI code should run only on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement the `GTInstaTableViewCell.m` method:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    self.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: In my code talking lot of memory how can i reduce memory also i am using asihttp to send image to server that also taking lot of memory how can i reduce memory usage in these 2 situation